# Android ICS displaying tabactivity tabs wrong

Tags: android, tabs, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tabactivity

I have an application using TabActivity but it is being rendered incorrectly on ICS. Not really interested in ActionBar or Fragments as a solution since the tabs still otherwise work for my and others applications.

Here is what it looks like on all other versions of android (the desired look)
[image]

and here is what it looks like on ICS, incorrect.

[image]

here is my tabactivity tab code, what needs to change?

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeMenuGroup.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("homeMenuGroup").setIndicator(li.inflate(R.layout.main_tabs_home, tabHost.getTabContentView(), false))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BuyTicketsGroup.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("buyTicketsGroup").setIndicator(li.inflate(R.layout.main_tabs_buy, tabHost.getTabContentView(), false))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, UseTicketsGroup.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("useTicketsGroup").setIndicator(li.inflate(R.layout.main_tabs_use, tabHost.getTabContentView(), false))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyAccountGroup.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("myAccountGroup").setIndicator(li.inflate(R.layout.main_tabs_account, tabHost.getTabContentView(), false))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and here is one of my tab button layout xml `R.layout.main_tabs_account`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:background="@drawable/switcher_account"
      android:layout_width="80dip"
      android:layout_height="60dip"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tough to give you a definitive answer. For example, your cited `R.layout.main_tabs_account` layout does not include an `ImageView`, which the screenshot displays, suggesting that something is out of sync within your question.

That being said, here's what I would try:

- Move your dimensions from the `TextView` to the `LinearLayout`. Your text is not supposed to be 80x60 dip; your tabs presumably are.
- Consider posting the layout that contains your `TabHost` and `TabWidget`, as that may offer more clues.
- Take a peek at [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DynamicTab), where I use customized tabs, and see if anything in how I am approaching it helps you. This project works fine on Android 4.0.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out about the `main_tabs_content`. it is a textview with a background drawable that has states. I'll see what happens about removing the linearlayout and changing the textview to an imageview

Comment: it worked. thanks for replying I hashed it out just reading your recommendations and what I imagined might be wrong. testing on other 2.x devices just to make sure I retained compabitility